# How to put a row_number expression in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this query with a row_number for a temporary id

```
    SET @row_number = 0; 
    SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS id, 'neighborhoods', 
    COUNT('neighborhoods') as count FROM 'data' GROUP BY 'neighborhoods' ORDER BY @row_number
```

In laravel I use a `DB:raw` for the query. But I wonder if laravel eloquent can be used for this kind of case or only I can use `DB:raw`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Laravel 8.17.0, there is no Eloquent method to set SQL variable. You will have to use the `DB::raw()` or `DB::statement()` function